# Devil damage resistance: is silver and magical in "or" or "and" relation?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance

In monster manual it states

> bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing
>   from non magical attacks not made with silvered weapons

I think it means "non-magical" or "not silvered", meaning either can overcome, but can you help with RAW?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing.

Comment: I've closed your question because I believed it is approximately identical to marked question. If you do not believe this to be the case, please [edit] to explain why/how. Your question can always be reopened